# unixODBC yields ORA-12154 TNS resolve error while sqlplus works just fine

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle11g, odbc, unixodbc

I am having a strange error when setting up a unixODBC connection to a Oracle 11g R1 database. After everything was set up I wanted to try to test the connection using isql. It keeps on returning the error

```
[08004][unixODBC][Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

What is confusing to me is that I can connect via `sqlplus` using the same environment and TNS notation just fine

```
sqlplus dbuser/password@DBOPBAC9
Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>
```

I am working on the problems for two days now and can't find a solution. ORA-12154 is a common error for which I have found a lot of possible solutions. But none of them worked for me. It is frustraiting.

Here is what I have tryed:

**Environment variables that are mentioned are all set before starting isql**

```
ORACLE_SID=DBOPBAC9
ORACLE_BASE=/CSGPBAC9/DBA/oracle
ORACLE_INSTANT_CLIENT_64=/CSGPBAC9/opt/myuser/tools/instantclient_11_2_x64
ORACLE_HOME=/CSGPBAC9/DBA/oracle/product/11.2.0
TNS_ADMIN=/CSGPBAC9/DBA/oracle/product/11.2.0/network/admin
```

**This is the tnsnames.ora found in $TNS_ADMIN directory**

```
DBOPBAC9 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host IP)(PORT = 1480))
  (CONNECT_DATA =
    (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    (SERVICE_NAME = DBOPBAC9)
  )
)
```

**This is the sqlnet.ora**

```
TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT = OFF
SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME = 10
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH = (TNSNAMES)
DIAG_ADR_ENABLED=off
```

**This is my unixODBC setup.** I have installed unixODBC into directory `/opt/unixODBC` and set the environment variables accordingly. The `odbc.ini` is in directory `/opt/myuser/tools/unixODBC` and variables are also set.

**odbc.ini**

```
[OracleODBC-11g]
Application Attributes = T
Attributes = W
BatchAutocommitMode = IfAllSuccessful
BindAsFLOAT = F
CloseCursor = F
DisableDPM = F
DisableMTS = T
Driver = Oracle 11g ODBC driver
DSN = OracleODBC-11g
EXECSchemaOpt =
EXECSyntax = T
Failover = T
FailoverDelay = 10
FailoverRetryCount = 10
FetchBufferSize = 64000
ForceWCHAR = F
Lobs = T
Longs = T
MaxLargeData = 0
MetadataIdDefault = F
QueryTimeout = T
ResultSets = T
ServerName = //host.ip/DBOPBAC9
SQLGetData extensions = F
Translation DLL =
Translation Option = 0
DisableRULEHint = T
UserID =
StatementCache=F
CacheBufferSize=20
UseOCIDescribeAny=F
```

**odbcinst.ini**

```
[Oracle 11g ODBC driver]
Description     = Oracle ODBC driver for Oracle 11g
Driver          = 
Driver64        = /CSGPBAC9/opt/myuser/tools/instantclient_11_2_x64/libsqora.so.11.1
Setup           =
FileUsage       =
CPTimeout       =
CPReuse         =
```

[I have created a strace output](https://www.pastiebin.com/59a2d7f4bf98c) to check for errors but unfortunatly I can't find anything. To me it looks like it is able to find tnsnames.ora file and read it

Comment: What happens when you run a SELECT in SQL*Plus?

Comment: I'm not familiar with unixODBC, but it seems odd to me that parameter DSN in odbc.ini is 'OracleODBC-11g' and not 'DBOPBAC9'. I would try to change it.

Comment: @BobJarvis the statement is executed successfully.

Comment: @wolfrevokcats as far as I know this is a name I cal select how I want. I have tryed it anyways and the result did not change. I still get a TNS error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit odbc.ini

```
ServerName = TNS_ALIAS
```

Comment: DBOPBAC9 ist the name of the database (Oracle SID). I thought ServerName must be of form `host:port/db-name`

Comment: DBOPBAC9 is the name of the database (Oracle SID) and DBOPBAC9 is TNS alias.

Comment: To distinguish between the database names(SID) and the TNS_ALIAS, 
you must change the TNS_ALIAS(for example DBO9 or BAC9) in the tnsnames.ora file.